# How to test new data against a trained model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm a beginner in Machine Learning. At first, my model gave me an accuracy of 85.82%, which was good. But now I would like to test the model again total new data but I can't figure out what to add to the code as I can only get the test accuracy when the model is tested with validation data.

The following is my code:

Comment: run model.predict(X_new) where X_new is the new data (as you did with X_test, which essentially was "new" to your model/training)
On a different note, I don't see 85% accuracy. The highest seems to be 79.87% and on the test set it seems to be 75.35%.

Comment: yes I tried that, but would I need to process the new data the same I did for X_test? how would I specify what is X_test this time? if you can show me some code that would be helpful, Thanks, and yes sorry, I wrote different numbers

Comment: I guess you are the one that has to show the code/data ;). You might have to preprocess the data or maybe rearrange them to suit the model. Unless anyone knows the training  data and the new test data, we can't help you.

Comment: For you to get better response, you need to share your training data and also your desired output. I recommend you read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new data set in EXACTLY the same manner by which you created the original test set. The term exactly is important, If you pre=processed your training and validation data a you must do the same pre-processing on this new data.
One other approach is to split the training data into 3 groups, train, validation and test. You can do that with train test split as follows.

```
X_train, X_temp, Y_train, Y_temp = train_test_split(X, Y,train_size=.8 random_state = 1)
X_valid, X_test, Y_valid, Y_test = train_test_split(X_temp, Y_temp, train_size=.5, shuffle=False)
```

This will take your input set and use 80% of it for training, 10 % for validation and 10% for test. In your code what you called the test set is actually the validation set so when you did model.evaluate you got the same accuracy as you did for validation accuracy. So now in model.fit make validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid).  Now your test set is independent of the validation set so when you run model.evaluate you should get a somewhat different accuracy than that of the validation accuracy.